# Consulta de validación e insertar datos en PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Querría saber si la consulta está bien porque siempre me tira un error en la línea de `$data`:

> Warning: `mysqli_fetch_array()` expects parameter 1 to be `mysqli_result`, boolean given in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/Barber2.3/Barber2.0-admin/index.php` on line 322

Éste es el código PHP:

```
<?php
include('../db.php');
if (isset($_POST['agg'])) {
    $nom_inventario = $_POST['nom-inventario'];
    $stock = $_POST['stock'];
    $ctg = $_POST['ctg'];

    $check = "SELECT * FROM `inventario` WHERE nombre == '$nom_inventario' AND stock == '$stock' AND categoria == '$ctg' ";
    $rs = mysqli_query($con, $check);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
    if ($data[0] > 1) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('El implemento que desea agregar ya existe')</script>";
    } else {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `inventario` (`nombre`, `stock`, `categoria`,`fecha-registro`) VALUES ('$nom_inventario','$stock,'$ctg','fecha-registro')";
        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
            echo '<script>alert("Nuevo implemento agregado") </script>';
        } else {
            echo '<script>alert("Lo Siento ! Revisar el sistema") </script>';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: ¿Que error te da?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Barber2.3/Barber2.0-admin/index.php on line 322

Comment: Eso es por lo que te ha dicho @OscarGarcia

Comment: Lee sobre inyección SQL y XSS. Este código es potencialmente vulnerable a esos tipos de ataque y no debería usarse en entornos de cara al público por los riesgos que conlleva.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro lo tendre presente, gracias por los consejos y ayudas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes un error de sintaxis SQL que provoca que tu variable `$rs` valga `false` y por ello te lanza el error al hacer un [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_array) sobre un recurso booleano.

También tienes otro error durante el `INSERT` en el que te faltaban unas comillas en `'$nom_inventario', '$stock, '$ctg', 'fecha-registro'`.

Las comprobaciones en SQL usan un único signo de igualdad (`=`) en vez de dos (`==`) como has usado en tu código. Debes acostumbrarte a comprobar la salida de las consultas para saber si ocurrió un error en ellas:

```
<?php
include('../db.php');
if (isset($_POST['agg'])) {
    $nom_inventario = $_POST['nom-inventario'];
    $stock = $_POST['stock'];
    $ctg = $_POST['ctg'];

    /* Uso "mysqli_real_escape_string()" para escapar las cadenas */
    $check = "
      SELECT *
      FROM `inventario`
      WHERE
        nombre = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $nom_inventario) . "'
        AND stock = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $stock) . "'
        AND categoria = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $ctg) . "'
    ";
    $rs = mysqli_query($con, $check);
    /* Comprobamos si hubo un error durante la ejecución de la consulta */
    if ($rs === false) {
        die('ERROR SQL: ' . htmlspecialchars(mysqli_error($con)));
    }
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
    if ($data[0] > 1) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('El implemento que desea agregar ya existe')</script>";
    } else {
        /* También hay que escapar aquí las cadenas */
        $sql = "
          INSERT INTO `inventario` (
            `nombre`,
            `stock`,
            `categoria`,
            `fecha-registro`
          ) VALUES (
            '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $nom_inventario) . "',
            '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $stock) . "',
            '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $ctg) . "',
            'fecha-registro'
          )
        ";
        if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
            echo '<script>alert("Nuevo implemento agregado") </script>';
        } else {
            echo '<script>alert("Lo Siento ! Revisar el sistema") </script>';
        }
    }
}
```

No hay que olvidar usar [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) para no sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) al concatenar cadenas de texto a consultas SQL.

Por último, hacer un `SELECT` para comprobar la existencia de un registro y posteriormente un `INSERT` para agregarlo es innecesario si agregas los campos necesarios (aparentemente en tu caso son `nombre`. `stock` (?) y `categoria`) a una clave única.

Comment: Se llama idinventarios y es autoincrement

Comment: Este era el error que me generaba: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Barber2.3/Barber2.0-admin/index.php on line 322 ,   probare tus correcciones

Comment: Justo lo que imaginé... el error *mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given* significa que *mysqli_fetch_array() espera que el parámetro 1 sea un mysqli_result, proporcionaste un boolean*. Es decir, que `$rs` es un booleano (`false`) por fallar la consulta SQL. No confundas las claves primarias con las claves únicas y los índices. Sólo puedes tener una única clave primaria, pero puedes tener tantos índices y claves únicas como desees y que afecten a tantos campos como necesites.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió tu aporte!